# Insert dynamic Object property names into Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-insert

Alright so I have an insert query that I would like to run but the issue I am having is with getting object properties/values that I need to insert.
Say I have a query that looks like the one below.

```
$this->db->insert('tblitems_in', array(
    'platform' => $item['Platform'],
    'ram' => $item['RAM'],
    'qty' => $item['qty'],
    'rate' => number_format($item['rate'], 2, '.', ''),
    'rel_id' => $insert_id,
    'rel_type' => 'estimate',
    'item_order' => $item['order'],
    'unit' => $item['unit']
));
```

This works fine when the person chooses RAM on the webpage which sets the $item Objects property 'RAM' to the value that was picked. Now if they choose HardDrive, that properties name is now sent as 'HardDrive' with the value they chose. Is there a way that i Could replace the 'ram'  and 'RAM' from the below example with a variable so I could change what the property name is that I would like to insert and insert into the corresponding db column?

**EDIT:**

I should have added that the options on the webpage are also dynamically created from a database so I do not know at the time of coding what the property names are. They could be RAM, HardDrive, Processor, maybe even Elephant. I was hoping I could use variables so that I could look at the DB used to create the webpage so that I know the property names and then dynamically add those names into the query.

**EDIT:**

Right now I am using the following code in order to get all the possible options that can be received from the webpage from a DB the webpages uses to create itself.

`$plat_options = $this->db->get('tblplatform_options')->row()->name;`

In the database right now it is only populated with names RAM and HardDrive to make things known for testing purposes. So this returns  $plat_options = {RAM, HardDrive}. I now have to figure out how to test is $item has these(RAM and HardDrive) as properties and if $item does have them then add them into the query previously shown.

Comment: Yes there is a way. What have you tried? Instead of creating the array in the function, create it before you call the function. That way you can decide which items to add to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an array of key => variable names, then loop over those values to see if they exist in the `$item` variable and, if so, add that value to the data to be inserted into the db:

```
//default array of data to insert
$data = [
    'platform' => $item['Platform'],
    'qty' => $item['qty'],
    'rate' => number_format($item['rate'], 2, '.', ''),
    'rel_id' => $insert_id,
    'rel_type' => 'estimate',
    'item_order' => $item['order'],
    'unit' => $item['unit']
];

//Get column names from db
$plat_options = $this->db->get('tblplatform_options')->row()->name;
// $plat_options = [RAM, HardDrive]

//Check if $item[$name] exists. If it does, add that to the
// array of data to be inserted
foreach($plat_options as $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $item)) {
        $data[$key] = $item[$key];
    }
}

$this->db->insert('tblitems_in', $data);
```

### edit

I'm not sure this will work (I don't understand the use case).

It is possible, using `array_diff_key` to get a list of array keys that exist in `$item` but not in `$data`. With this array of keys, you can add the missing keys.

I have altered my previous code to demonstrate this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the property names are unknown during the coding process and will be pulled from a DB which is why I would like to use variables.

Comment: I don't have the program open at the moment but is there a way in $columns to replace 'ram','RAM','hd' and 'HARDDRIVE' with variables? I will give it a try in a few minutes if not to try and figure out if I can.

Comment: I tried out your code but wasn't able to get it to work. For example $item['RAM] exists and in the database the column name 'RAM' also exists but $item['RAM']  isn't added into the query that is run. I have also updated my post to show how and what I am getting from my DB to check the Object properties against.

Comment: That did it. I also messed up getting my option names from my database. I forgot that row() only grabs the first row.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the array one element at a time based on whatever field data you received. I used a switch statement, but it could be a simple if/then/else as well.

```
$data_array = array();
$data_array['platform'] = $item['Platform']
switch($item['Object'] {
    case 'HardDrive':
        $data_array['harddrive'] = $item['HardDrive'];
        break;
    case 'RAM':
        $data_array['ram'] = $item['RAM'];
        break;
}
$data_array['qty'] = $item['qty'];
$data_array['rate' = number_format($item['rate'], 2, '.', '');
$data_array['rel_id'] = $insert_id;
$data_array['rel_type' = 'estimate';
$data_array['item_order'] = $item['order'];
$data_array['unit'] = $item['unit'];


$this->db->insert('tblitems_in', $data_array);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the property names are unknown during the coding process and will be pulled from a DB which is why I would like to use variables.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You could loop through those rows and build your data array pretty easily.

Comment: I feel like it should be something simple to do yet I'm having trouble doing it.

Comment: When you have all of the pieces, start a new question and include the schemas of the tables, and some sample data (a few related rows should do). Explain what you have tried, and what you are expecting as a result. If the DB part or the coding part is beyond your current expertise, consider hiring a consultant to write the code for you. SO can help you get past sticking points, but this isn't a place to get design help or have someone write the code.

Comment: I really just need help getting variables in place of 'ram' and 'RAM'. I figured I could just replace them with something like $test and have, for example, $test=RAM; but it doesn't seem to work. I have everything else.

Comment: Because you need to change both the data source and the column name, right?

Comment: The code in my answer above does what you describe. Instead of a switch/case, you could use simple if/then to make the changes to the array.